# Signin failure for Huawei IAP via Unity Distribution Portal, in logs it says error code 907135001

Tags: unity-game-engine, huawei-developers, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-iap

We are trying to connect Huawei IAP via Unity Distribution Portal, but having an issue on “sign-in” stage w/ logs below. It says sign in failed w/ status 907135001. I tried to search on Huawei develop website but no any information for this error code. Any one can help?

```
2020-12-02 12:35:47.626 6980-6988/? I/UnityDistPlatform: [ HUAWEI] sign in failed , status : 997135001 
2020-12-02 12:35:47.626 6980-6980/? I/UnityDistPlatform: [ HUAWEI] Setup finished. 
2020-12-02 12:35:47.714 6982-6980/? I/UnityDistPlatform: [ HUAWEI] Init Fail: sign in failed 
2020-12-02 12:35:47.721 6982-6980/? I/UnityDistPlatform: [ HUAWEI] UDP Version : v2.0.0 
2020-12-02 12:35:47.722 6980-6980/? D/UnityDistPlatform: [ HUAWEI] DeviceId (android):c716ce5df161065a , Clientid : h2T5 - guv9QtkF095vyL5eQ
```

Comment: Please use the [latest HMS Core version](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-Guides-V5/hmssdk-kit-0000001050042513-V5) as @Zinna said. If it does not fix the issue, please provide more info, like your integration steps, etc. :)

Answer (score 1):

Old HMS core will have the issue. Please use the latest HMS Core version, which should resolve this issue. Please let me know if you still experience this issue with latest HMS Core.

Comment: Thank Zinna and Shirley for the guide and help!